# arraylist from 2d to 1d

Tags: grails, arraylist

i have a arraylist and i want to make query

```
def teams = province.competitions.teams

def fromTansfer = Transfer.withCriteria {
   'in'("teamOld",teams)
   eq("time", 0)
   eq("year", 2014)
   order("teamOld", "desc")
}
```

The result from teams is a 2D arraylist and the withCriteria have a problem with the in statement:

Teams:

```
   TransferController  [[FC Munderfing, USV Raiffeisen Eggelsberg/Moosdorf, FC Münzkirchen, Union Stampfl-Bau Ostermiething, Union Peuerbach, Union CARIBAS Diersbach, Union VTA Rottenbach, Union Ziegelwerk], [...], [...]]
```

I think there is the problem that the Arraylist is 2D. How can i convert it in a 1D?

The error is:

```
caused exception: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of test.Team.id
```

How can i fix it ?

The solution:

```
 def teams = province.competitions.teams.flatten()
```

Thx joe69

Comment: I am not sure that your error message is really tied to your 2D list problem.

Answer (score 2):

If `teams` is a List of List and you want to flatten all of that out into 1 big List, call `teams.flatten()`.

Comment: Note that `teams.flatten()` does not mutate the List.  It returns a new List which contains the flattened data so you may want something like `'in'("teamOld",teams.flatten())`.  The return value of the call to `.flatten()` is the flattened List.  `teams` will be left as it was.  I hope that makes sense.